# Location and Size of the controls on a Form change after the Form is maximized

Tags: vb.net

I have a Form called `formmain`. When I open another Form, `formmain` is  minimized.
My problem is that when I restore `formmain`, the Location and Size of the controls on it have changed completely.
I am using the following method when the Form is resized:

```
Public Sub ResizeForm(ObjForm As Form, DesignerHeight As Integer, DesignerWidth As Integer)
    '#Region "Code for Resizing and Font Change According to Resolution"
    'Specify Here the Resolution Y component in which this form is designed
    'For Example if the Form is Designed at 800 * 600 Resolution then DesignerHeight=600
    Dim i_StandardHeight As Integer = DesignerHeight

    'Specify Here the Resolution X component in which this form is designed
    'For Example if the Form is Designed at 800 * 600 Resolution then DesignerWidth=800
    Dim i_StandardWidth As Integer = DesignerWidth
    Dim i_PresentHeight As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height

    'Present Resolution Height
    Dim i_PresentWidth As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width

    'Presnet Resolution Width
    f_HeightRatio = CSng(CSng(i_PresentHeight) / CSng(i_StandardHeight))
    f_WidthRatio = CSng(CSng(i_PresentWidth) / CSng(i_StandardWidth))
    ObjForm.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.None

    'Make the Autoscale Mode=None
    ObjForm.Scale(New SizeF(f_WidthRatio, f_HeightRatio))
    For Each c As Control In ObjForm.Controls
        If c.HasChildren Then
            ResizeControlStore(c)
        Else
            c.Font = New Font(c.Font.FontFamily, c.Font.Size * f_HeightRatio, c.Font.Style, c.Font.Unit, CByte(0))
        End If
    Next
    ObjForm.Font = New Font(ObjForm.Font.FontFamily, ObjForm.Font.Size * f_HeightRatio, ObjForm.Font.Style, ObjForm.Font.Unit, CByte(0))
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have some active procedure that performs layout logic when the Form is resized? Some specific anchoring and/or docking that is performed at run-time? Something else? Your question is somewhat lacking in details.

Comment: no doch and i use anchor

Comment: i edited the question details

Comment: thanks _ jimi the problem was in the the sub i use when it resized.

Comment: You could add a condition in the Form's Resize event (or where the `ResizeForm` method is called):  `If Me.WindowState <> FormWindowState.Maximized And Me.WindowState <> FormWindowState.Minimized Then  'Call the  ResizeForm method  End If`

Comment: Allright. You could also substitute this resizing logic (which I can't test because some pieces are missing) with a combination of `FlowLayoutPanels` and `TableLayoutPanels`. The latter probably fits better given the resize method you're using now.